# Calculation Not Updating

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I have been running this syntax with one variable successfully, but now I am trying to change it to a `foeach()` loop and take a range of values and show the results as a message box.  My issue with the syntax is that `ecll` always retains the value of the first number passed, and the calculation is never updated for each subsequent number in the array.

Where did I err that is preventing this from being updated for each subsequent number in the array?

```
private void btnGetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int start = 2;
  int end = 10;

  int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();

  foreach (int n in nums)
  {  
      float tp_x = 0, tp_y = 0;

      SAP = new List<PointF>();
      float fbw = m_pd.bl[m_pd.bl.Count - 1].m_Width;
      float Location1_X = tp_x + fbw;
      float Location1_Y = tp_y;
      SAP.Add(new PointF(Location1_X, Location1_Y));

      float iBH = gbh(m_pd.bl.Count - 1);
      float lbw = m_pd.bl[0].m_Width;
      float Location2_X = tp_x + lbw;
      float Location2_Y = tp_y + (iBH) + 1.5f;

      PointF rip = new PointF();
      if (!Getrip(ftp, rhep, ref rip))
      {
        SAP = null;
        return;
      }

      for (int iRowIndex = saii; iRowIndex < m_pd.pp.Count; iRowIndex++)
      {
        float Xvalue = m_pd.pp[iRowIndex].X;
        float Yvalue = m_pd.pp[iRowIndex].Y;
        SAP.Add(new PointF(Xvalue, Yvalue));

        if (Yvalue == LeftIntersectionPoint.Y)
        {
          pp.X = Xvalue;
          pp.Y = Yvalue;
          continue;
        }

        if (Xvalue >= rip.X)
        {
          Xvalue = rip.X;
          SAP[SAP.Count - 1] = new PointF(rip.X, rip.Y);
        }

        if (Xvalue == rip.X)
        {
          break;
        }

        pp.X = Xvalue;
        pp.Y = Yvalue;
      }

      double ecll = Getll(Location1_X, Location1_Y, rip.X, rip.Y);

      Messagebox.Show(Convert.ToString(ec11));
      txtLength.Text = ll.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now is the time to learn how to use the debugger of your toolset of choice.

Comment: @nvoigt - I am using VS2017 - I have used the Debugger and the Immediate window and tracked the problem down to Location1_X & Location1_Y not changing values when n is changed.  But I do not see why not.

Comment: They are set at one single point. You can put a breakpoint there. They don't seem dependent on `n`, why would you expect them to change? `tp_x` and `tp_y` will always be zero at that point.

Comment: My apalogy - the issue is with my variables rip.X & rip.Y - when they reach the line double ec11..... they always hold the same value.

Comment: @SmithStanley it is in relation to what nvoigt is saying though: from what I can see in your function call, "n" is never used. As such, nothing is going to change throughout the various passes. How is n (or since it worked before, the nums collection) intended to be used?

Comment: Move out the loop variables that are not changed in the loop like `tp_x`, `tp_y` and others.

Comment: `rip` is set only through the `ref` in your `Getrip` method... which we don't know. Why it doesn't change is as trivial as it is unknown to us. Debug it and find out.

Comment: @nvoigt - would it help if I provided the syntax before I change it to foreach loop and maybe you can asses what step I missed?

Comment: judging by where you create nums, It feels like you're trying to isolate a series of elements in another collection. Spitballing an assumption (as I don't know what you're attempting to do), it looks like it would be where you set float fbw. Maybe m_pd.bl[n].m_width? And if that's the case, probably on iBH call as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this is more of a comment based on what's going on here, but I kind of need the code section to explain this better I believe.

Let's simplify away from your points, widths, etc. I think we can all agree that n is never used within your function, so let's do a similar example:

So I have a function I wrote that adds 1 to 1

```
var newNum = 1 + 1;
```

It does what is expected, sets newNum to 2, but let's say I wanted to enhance it so that it adds 1 to the numbers in nums (from your original function):

```
int start = 2;
int end = 10;

int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();
```

but if I try to reuse my function outright:

```
foreach (int n in nums)
{
  var newNum = 1 + 1;
}
```

Every single pass, I'm always going to have newNum set at 2 because I'm not using the variable.

what I should do is write this:

```
foreach (int n in nums)
{
  var newNum = 1 + n;
}
```

so based on your 2 through 10, I should see newNum set to 3 through 11 at various iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration in the 'Foreach' loop assigns a new value to 'n'.
However in the loop body, that value (n) is not used anywhere in the calculations (unless I am missing something). So, of course the result of these calculations will always be the same.

As soon as you include 'n' in some of the calclations, the result will change...

Comment: but before I modifed the code to include a foreach loop the value of the single variable (which i change to array) was not used in the calculation for rip.x & rip.y. That is why I did not include it in my alteration.

Comment: but the way it is currently written, you're not using nums/n beyond just saying "spit out the result n number of times"

Comment: If the single variable has no impact on the calculation, why do you expect several different values for that variable to change the result?